# magento import export csv error sku

Tags: magento, csv, import, export

I had problem so i had to re install my whole magento site and i exported my products in csv with two method.
With Import and With Dataflow - Profiles.
I recreated the categories and i try to import the files but it gives error for every single product.
"Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined."
I don't know how could i fix because i have sku for every item.

I tried also the same two method to import.
I didnt work out.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can put a `Mage::log(var_export($importData, 1))`  in Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveRow(), it seems that there is where the error is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today.

There is a setting on both import and export called:

> **Original Magento attribute names in first row:** Yes/No

This puts the column name on the top row of the CSV.

When exporting the data I had this set to **NO**, but when importing I had it set to **YES**. The solution for me was to have both set to **YES**.

Hope that helps.